# php system() function calling cgi on IIS7 vs Apache

Tags: php, apache, iis, iis-7

On Apache the code below will run index.cgi and return the content of cgi to php page

```
    <?php
    $command= './cgi-bin/index.cgi';
    echo system($command);
    ?>
```

On IIS this doesn't seem to work that way. How can I have the same behavior on IIS 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

This is why: The command `./cgi-bin/index.cgi` does either not exists on IIS or is not executable on the IIS platform. This is a command that is dependent to the computer system the PHP script is installed on.

On IIS you need to create code that is cross-platform compatible. It needs to choose another command that does the same like `./cgi-bin/index.cgi` but actually works on the IIS platform.

Probably not the answer you would like to hear. Probably you can say what that CGI script does and we can find a solution. Alternatively you can add the code from that file to your question.

Comment: this cgi works on IIS when accessed through browser. It works also in Apache. It doesn't seem so on IIS.

Comment: By executable do you mean that I should associate .cgi with the exe (which is rebol.exe) for it to work on IIS like on Apache ?

Comment: Try to set the correct windows path to the script. Probably with `realpath('./cgi-bin/index.cgi')`;

Comment: finally it's due to path which should have \\ on windows. thanks for help.